# httpRequest.getSession(true) method returns null in weblogic 12.1.2

Tags: java, java-8, weblogic, weblogic12c, httpsession

I am using below code to get http session.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
```

This works fine in glassfish server.
But it return a null value in weblogic server (version - 12.1.2).

Is any one can describe how to fix this issue. it will be great helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a bug or misconfiguration of weblogic. `request.getSession(true)` should never return null, it's equivalent to `request.getSession()`: if HttpSessions doesn't exists, it creates a new one. Only `request.getSession(false)` can return null

Answer (score 0):

The only way that request.getSession(true) can return null is if the 
number of active sessions exceeds maxActiveSessions

Comment: Thank u for your answer.But in return null still with the very small active sessions.